# Name of this idiom? myFont.setWidth(20).setStyle(Style.BOLD).setX().setY().setZ() (...)

Tags: idioms

Is there a standard way to refer to this idiom of "telescopic" method call chaining?

myFont.setWidth(20).setStyle(Style.BOLD).setX().setY().setZ() (...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A library that uses this style is said to have *Fluent API* or *Fluent interface*. An example of this is a [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) library.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple called "Method chaining" according to wikipedia
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining